# Header bar color is not user friendly

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

The color of your header bar is so similar to the chrome of my browser that I just spent a stupid amount of time trying to find where the search box was. I was ignoring it at the top because I didn't realize it was part of the page.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Google to change the color of their browser?  :-)

Comment: The colour you suggested changing it to is identical to the theme I use in my browser.

Comment: +1 for making my morning humorous. :)

Comment: Hey guys, I just wanted to point out that I was right and that Stack Exchange only took 2 years to realize it. Loving the new Black bar. :)

Answer (score 6):

The bar's color is fine to me; Chrome's top bar has a bottom border to separate the UI from the viewport.

Plus, something won't be changed just to make it nice on one browser. It has to be a major change that would affect the layout/design on every browser.

I suggest that if you still find this to be a problem, you should consider installing a theme with darker colors.

**EDIT:** I misread your original post—no matter what browser you're on, the original point still stands. An entire design aspect won't be changed just to satisfy users of a single browser.

Comment: All I'm saying is, any form of Grey is going to blend in.

Comment: See StackExchange.